# Not iterating other links

Tags: python, scrapy

Hello guys i am trying to parse ingredients from a website,but when i run the code  in the ingredients key in shows only one ingredient and not going through other ingredients.
Thank you for your time

```
class RecipiesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'recipies'
allowed_domains = ['www.epicurious.com/search?content=recipe']
start_urls = ['https://www.epicurious.com/search?content=recipe']

def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath("//article[@class='recipe-content-card']/a[2]/@href")
    for link in links:
        yield response.follow(link.get(), callback=self.parse_recipie, dont_filter=True)

def parse_recipie(self, response):
    the_recipie = {}
    list_to_append_in_dictionary = []

    the_recipie['name'] = response.xpath("//h1[1]/text()").get()
    #here are  links contaning the divs of ingredientswhich have the same name class
    ingredients = response.xpath("//div[@class='List-XYTyX gPuEKn']/div[@class='BaseWrap-sc-TURhJ BaseText-fFzBQt Description-dSNklj eTiIvU eftAc']")
    
    for ingredients_of_recipie in ingredients:
        if "ingredients" in the_recipie:
            list_to_append_in_dictionary.append(response.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[@class='BaseWrap-sc-TURhJ BaseText-fFzBQt Description-dSNklj eTiIvU eftAc']/text())").get())
            
        else:
            list_to_append_in_dictionary.append(response.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[@class='BaseWrap-sc-TURhJ BaseText-fFzBQt Description-dSNklj eTiIvU eftAc']/text())").get()) 
            the_recipie["ingredients"] = list_to_append_in_dictionary

        
            
    yield the_recipie
```

The results are:

```
{'name': 'Ginger Pudding', 'ingredients': ['100 g (about ¼ cup plus 2 tablespoons) grated ginger', '100 g (about ¼ cup plus 2 tablespoons) grated ginger', '100 g (about ¼ cup plus 2 tablespoons) grated ginger']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Data is loaded dynamically by javascript from xhr fully and scrapy can't render javascript. So to grab data you need an automation tools something like `re/json/selenium with scrapy`. Here I use `json`.

## script:

```
import scrapy
import json
class EpiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'epi'
    # allowed_domains = ["www.epicurious.com"]
    # start_urls = ['https://www.epicurious.com/search/?content=recipe&page=2']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request (
            url='https://www.epicurious.com/search?content=recipe&page=2&xhr=true',
            method='GET',
            callback = self.parse,
            headers={'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
            )
    def parse(self, response):
        #resp=json.loads(response.body)
        #resp=json.loads(response.text)
        resp= response.json()['items']
        #print(resp)

        for item in resp:
            name=item['photoData']['title']
            #print(name)
            ingredients=''.join(item['ingredients'])
            #print(ingredients)

            yield {
                'Name': name,
                'Ingredients':ingredients
                }
```

## Output:

```
{'Name': 'Mince Pies - RECIPE', 'Ingredients': '1¼ cup (175g) currants1¼ cup (175g) large dark raisins6 oz (175g) stewing apple, in small pieces⅓ cup (50 g) candied orange peel2 oz (50 g) prunes, pitted and chopped½ cup (115g) butter, frozen and grated½ cup (115g) soft brown sugar½ tsp. ground cinnamon½ tsp. ground mace½ tsp. ground cloves¼ tsp. ground nutmeg¼ tsp. ground gingerPinch of sea salt½ lemon or Seville orange, zest, and juice1 cup brandy or rum (or half sherry, half rum) or as needed1½ cups (180g) all-purpose flour2 Tbsp. (20g) confectioners’ 
sugarPinch of sea salt7 Tbsp. (100g) chilled butter, diced1 Tbsp. cold water1 egg yolkButter, for greasingFlour, for dusting1 egg yolk1 Tbsp. milk'}
2021-12-20 09:20:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.epicurious.com/search?content=recipe&page=2&xhr=true>
{'Name': 'Classic Champagne Cocktail', 'Ingredients': '1 sugar cubeAngostura bittersChampagne or sparkling wine, chilledLemon or orange twist, for garnish'}
2021-12-20 09:20:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.epicurious.com/search?content=recipe&page=2&xhr=true>
{'Name': 'Chocolate Baking Shapes - HERO', 'Ingredients': '1 tablespoon (7 g) ground flaxseed3 tablespoons (45 ml) water¾ cup (170 g) nondairy, nonhydrogenated butter (such as Earth Balance)1 cup (200 g) granulated vegan sugar1 teaspoon (5 ml) vanilla extract1¼ cups (155 g) whole-wheat pastry flour⅓ cup (40 g) unsweetened cocoa powder½ teaspoon baking soda½ teaspoon baking powder (look for aluminum-free)¼ teaspoon salt1 cup (175 g) nondairy semisweet chocolate or peanut butter chips'}
2021-12-20 09:20:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.epicurious.com/search?content=recipe&page=2&xhr=true>
{'Name': "Nonna's Biscotti", 'Ingredients': '1 cup sugar1 stick unsalted butter, melted3 tablespoons brandy2 teaspoons pure almond extract1 teaspoon pure vanilla extract1 cup whole almonds with skin, lightly toasted, cooled, and coarsely chopped3 large eggs2¾ cups all-purpose flour1½ teaspoons baking powder¼ teaspoon salt'}
2021-12-20 09:20:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.epicurious.com/search?content=recipe&page=2&xhr=true>
```

.. so on